# How to download the raw log files from splunk

Tags: logging, splunk

Where I work they just switched to splunk, but I just need the raw log file so I can work with it in notepad++ for debugging.  So my question is can I get the raw log file from splunk, I don't need any of the "features" of splunk I just need the raw log files.  So how can I get that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `index=<...> | fields _raw`

Then, you can export the files in CSV format. https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Search/ExportdatausingSplunkWeb

What do you need to do in notepad++ that you can't do in Splunk directly?

Comment: Sorry on the delay of accepting the answer, but this is what I needed thanks.

Comment: the problem is, that you need a search first to be able to download it. I'm in the same boat as the original poster. I want to look at log files, scroll through them, find errors and warnings, look for things that seem strange, anything that you usually do with a log file. Finding errors in your log files with splunk is a nightmare.